# Multiple DIFFERENT nameservers in a DNS record

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, nameserver, mx-record

I recently moved my hosted website to a friends hosting, in order to do this I changed my DNS nameservers but this has broken a few things, firstly I cannot control subdomains, and secondly my MX records are missing (to do with how I set it up probably)

as far as the MX records are concerned I think my friend will have to set them at his end but as for subdomains, if I set the third and fourth nameservers back to the default for 1&2 (entry 1&2 are the new nameservers, entries 3&4 are the old ones), when it fails the lookup on the subdomain will it check for the subdomain on the next nameserver(s) that were specified?

I don't really know that much about DNS but I still need a sub-domain to point to the old hosting and I need to restore my MX records, hopefully as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS resolvers won't try a different nameserver when the first one they pick returns an error. All your nameservers need to serve identical content.

Comment: Any idea of a better way to do this? I have thought of perhaps setting the nameserver back to the default and then setting the one particular domain my friend is hosting to a CNAME for one of his domains, then as long as he keeps the config for my domain then the requests will still look as though they are coming from my site and they will be going to the same IP address they should be so it would in theory serve the right content, but something tells me this might not be as easy as that...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your problem, which is that your new DNS servers are not configured properly. There no `"oops, I migrated a critical service without knowing what the hell I was doing"` option.

Once you have a *working* DNS infrastructure with your new host, you can set up additional DNS servers as slaves to the master with the correct configuration. This way, all of your zones stay identical across all name servers.

There's no way to tell a client that a server is authoritative for your zone unless it doesn't have the record you want. It's either authoritative or it isn't.